# How to start a function ONLY on a button click

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I am looking to have my grid style game start once I click the start button on my page. Currently the game starts as soon as I click the grid, but I want this function to be invoked only when the you click the Start Button.

I already created my game Board. Which can be called using this function: createBoard(). Styling for this board is full of my divs and working.

**I tried the solutions previously given in my other thread and still had an issue with the function not invoking only at the click of a start button.**

Here is my replit: Any feedback on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks! :)

https://replit.com/@batb/WholeFrostyLocus

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const grid = document.querySelector('.grid')
  const startBtn = document.querySelector('.button-one')
  const pauseBtn = document.querySelector('.button-two')
  const scoreDisplay = document.querySelector('.score')
  const countdown = document.querySelector('.countdown')
  let paused = true
  let score = 100
  const width = 8
  const squares = []
  let isGameOver = false
  let buzzyAmount = 12
  let result = 0

  const fiBuzz = [
    'url(images/purple-fizzy.png)',
    'url(images/buzzy-green.png)',
    'url(images/new-moo-buzzy.png)',
    'url(images/new-shiny-fizzy.png)'
  ]

  //shuffled Arrays

  function createBoard() {

    const buzzArray = Array(buzzyAmount).fill('buzzy')
    const emptyArray = Array(width * width - buzzyAmount).fill('valid')
    const gameArray = emptyArray.concat(buzzArray)
    const shuffledArray = gameArray.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
   

    for (let i = 0; i < width * width; i++) {
      let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * fiBuzz.length)
      let square = document.createElement('div')
      square.setAttribute('id', i)
      square.setAttribute('draggable', 'true')
      square.classList.add(shuffledArray[i])
      grid.appendChild(square)
      squares.push(square)
      square.style.backgroundImage = fiBuzz[randomNumber]
      
       //normal click
       square.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        click(square)
      })
    }


  }
  
  createBoard()

  //check neighboring squares once square is clicked
  function checkSquare(square, currentId) {
    const isLeftEdge = (currentId % width === 0)
    const isRightEdge = (currentId % width === width -1)

    setTimeout(() => {
      if (currentId > 0 && !isLeftEdge) {
        const newId = squares[parseInt(currentId) -1].id
        //const newId = parseInt(currentId) - 1   ....refactor
        const newSquare = document.getElementById(newId)
        click(newSquare)
      }
      if (currentId > 7 && !isRightEdge) {
        const newId = squares[parseInt(currentId) +1 -width].id
        //const newId = parseInt(currentId) +1 -width   ....refactor
        const newSquare = document.getElementById(newId)
        click(newSquare)
      }
      if (currentId > 10) {
        const newId = squares[parseInt(currentId -width)].id
        //const newId = parseInt(currentId) -width   ....refactor
        const newSquare = document.getElementById(newId)
        click(newSquare)
      }
      if (currentId > 11 && !isLeftEdge) {
        const newId = squares[parseInt(currentId) -1 -width].id
        //const newId = parseInt(currentId) -1 -width   ....refactor
        const newSquare = document.getElementById(newId)
        click(newSquare)
      }
      if (currentId < 38 && !isRightEdge) {
        const newId = squares[parseInt(currentId) +1].id
        //const newId = parseInt(currentId) +1   ....refactor
        const newSquare = document.getElementById(newId)
        click(newSquare)
      }
      if (currentId < 40 && !isLeftEdge) {
        const newId = squares[parseInt(currentId) -1 +width].id
        //const newId = parseInt(currentId) -1 +width   ....refactor
        const newSquare = document.getElementById(newId)
        click(newSquare)
      }
      if (currentId < 45 && !isRightEdge) {
        const newId = squares[parseInt(currentId) +1 +width].id
        //const newId = parseInt(currentId) +1 +width   ....refactor
        const newSquare = document.getElementById(newId)
        click(newSquare)
      }
      if (currentId < 48) {
        const newId = squares[parseInt(currentId) +width].id
        //const newId = parseInt(currentId) +width   ....refactor
        const newSquare = document.getElementById(newId)
        click(newSquare)
      }
    }, 10)
  }


  // game over

  function gameOver(square) {
    scoreDisplay.innerHTML = score + '<br>'+ ' You Lose :('
     isGameOver = true
     clearInterval(timerId)
  
    // show ALL the badStars in gameOver 
    squares.forEach(square => { 
      if (square.classList.contains('buzzy')) {
      square.appendChild(document.createElement('img')).src = 'images/fizz-buzz-mix.png'
      square.classList.remove('buzzy')
      square.classList.add('checked')
      clearInterval(timerId)
      }
    })
  }

  function checkForWin() {

    let matches = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    if (score >= 100) {
      scoreDisplay.innerHTML = score + ': ' + ' You Win!'
    } else {
      scoreDisplay.innerHTML = score + ': ' + ' You Lose!'
    }
    clearInterval(timerId)
  }
  }

  // TIMER LOGIC

  const startingMinutes = .25
  let time = startingMinutes * 60
  let timerId
  let square

  function countDown() {

    let minutes = Math.floor(time / 60)
    let seconds = time % 60
    time--
    console.log(minutes, 'minutes:', seconds, 'seconds')

    
    if (time <= 0) {
      checkForWin()
      gameOver()
    }

    countdown.innerHTML = minutes + ' minutes ' + ': ' + seconds + ' seconds '
  }

  
  // add to right click

  function click(square) {

    let currentId = square.id
    if (isGameOver) return
    if (square.classList.contains('checked')) return score++
    if (square.classList.contains('buzzy')) {
        gameOver(square)
      } else {
        let total = square.getAttribute('data')
        if (total !=0) {
          square.classList.add('checked')
          if (total == 1) square.classList.add('one')
          if (total == 2) square.classList.add('two')
          if (total == 3) square.classList.add('three')
          if (total == 4) square.classList.add('four')
          square.innerHTML = total
          return
        }
        checkSquare(square, currentId)
      }
      square.classList.add('checked')
    }


  // START AND PAUSE LOGIC

function scoreFunction() {
    if(square.classList.contains('valid')) {
      score+=3
    }
  }

  startBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (paused === false) {

      score++
      return
    }
    scoreDisplay.innerHTML = 'Score' + ': ' + score++
    paused = false
    timerId = setInterval(countDown, 1000)

  })

  function pauseGame() {
    paused = true
    clearInterval(timerId) 
  }

  pauseBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    pauseGame()
  })
  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing up your html button so it calls the function you want once you click the button:

```
<button class="button-one" onclick="function_name"> Start </button>
```

instead of `fucntion_name` put the name of the function you want to call on the button click.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.